# Add the following flags: -objc-all_load

Tags: xcode4

Followed this link to add flags (Objc-all_load) :: http://experitest.com/studio/help2/WebHelp/index.htm#page=Connect_iOS_(iPhone,iPad)_-_for_NON-jailbroken_device.htm

But its not properly shown how to add that In Xcode -- Xcode>build settings>Other Linker Flags>Objc-all_load.

Answer (score 2):

Navigate and find the "Other Linker Flags" then just **double click** on it. Once there you can just push the "+" button in the popover to add your flag (Objc-all_load).

[image]

Comment: When you have entered your flag, to save it in configuration you will have to make the panel disappear by clicking on another line of the build settings. if you instead open another file in the editor xcode will _not_ save your flag! (weird..)